# Match List<string> to List<object> using LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, casting

Assume we have an input list with the following values (all are strings):

```
var listA = new List<string>();
listA.Add("test");
listA.Add("123");
listA.Add("5.7");
```

and we are also given a second list:

```
var listB = new List<object>();
listB.Add(typeof(string));
listB.Add(typeof(int));
listB.Add(typeof(float));
```

I want to verify if all values in ListA are in the right format by matching it with the list of types in ListB. Both list will have the same length.

If yes I'd like to get a List as return value where all values of ListA are stored in the format as specified in ListB.
If one converion would fail I would like to be able to throw a custom exception. Something like

```
throw new MyException($"Failed to convert value {valueX} to {type}");
```

I can only imagine a very ugly solution with for loops, lots of casts/conversions and copying. Is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: Firstly both lists have same variable, change that, next, how do you map type to the value, it is using index, that at 0th index it shall be this type, so 0th - string, 1st - int, 2nd - float. Also what solution you have created, update it, so that it can be known what exactly you expect over and above it

Comment: But `"123"` and `"5.7"` are still strings, and would fail any reasonable checks against `typeof(int)` and `typeof(float)`.

Comment: Do you need to support nullable types (i.e. `listB.Add(typeof(int?));`? I ask since if you do the problem is harder.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn How would this affect the solutions posted here? It is expected behavior that a check of 123 into string will fail, right?

Comment: @mjwills No support for nullable types is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2) the lists together, then use the [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8) Method

> Returns an object of a specified type whose value is equivalent to a
> specified object.

It will throw an exception of the following types

- `InvalidCastException` This conversion is not supported. -or- value is null and conversionType is a value type. -or- value does not
  implement the IConvertible interface.
- `FormatException` value is not in a format recognized by conversionType.
- `OverflowException` value represents a number that is out of the range of conversionType.
- `ArgumentNullException` conversionType is null.

**Example**

```
var listA = new List<string> { "test", "123", "5.7" };
var listB = new List<Type> { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(int) };
    
var combined = listA.Zip(listB, (s, type) => (Value :s, Type:type));

foreach (var item in combined)
{
   try
   {
      Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, item.Type);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to cast value {item.Value} to {item.Type}",ex);
   }
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lQgbnz)

<sub>**Side note**: Technically speaking this is not casting *per se*, it's changing/converting the type</sub>

Comment: Side note should be main note and written in caps lock ;)

Comment: "Technically speaking this is not casting per-se, its changing/converting the type" in what scenario would this be a problem?

Comment: @Kyu96 It isn't a problem - just a matter of using the right terminology.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following with Zip.

```
var result = listA.Zip(listB,(value,type)=> 
                        { 
                           try{return Convert.ChangeType(value,(Type)type);} 
                           catch{throw new Exception($"Cannot cast between value {value} to Type {type}");}
                        });
```

By having the conversion within the Zip, would ensure you wouldn't have to convert the whole list if there is an exception earlier in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to avoid `forloop` and do it with linq is still possible

Here is what i gott

```
var listA = new List<string>();
    listA.Add("test");
    listA.Add("123");
    listA.Add("5.7");

   var listB = new List<Type>();
    listB.Add(typeof(string));
    listB.Add(typeof(int));
    listB.Add(typeof(float));
   var index =-1;

try{
var newList = listA.Select((x, i)=>  Convert.ChangeType(x, listB[(index = i)])).ToList();

}catch(Exception e){

 throw  new Exception("Failed to cast value "+listA[index]+" to "+listB[index]);

}
```